# How can I know if my MacBook pro supports 8 gb or not?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, compatibility

Here is my serial number:

[image: My Mac]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP544

4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1066MHz DDR3 memory; two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB

A cool trick in case you want to find more about it is you can type your serial number right into the support search on the apple site and it will bring up your model and specification article. Take a look: http://support.apple.com/specs/#w89253hx64c

Comment: Nice tip on entering the serial directly into the Apple Support search box.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify whether you have the 15" or 17" model, but both support 8GB of RAM.  Crucial.com has a great "[Memory Advisor Tool](http://www.crucial.com/mac/index.aspx)" to help you find the memory specs of any computer.

[Here are the specs of a 15" MacBook Pro](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=MacBook%20Pro%203.06GHz%20Intel%20Core%202%20Duo%20%2815-inch%20DDR3%29%20Mid-2009&pl=Apple&cat=RAM) that matches the "About This Mac" screenshot you linked to above.

[image: Crucial Memory Advisor Tool]

Answer (score 2):

[Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca) is excellent for this sort of thing.  It has an iPhone version, is on the Mac App Store, and is free.

Comment: Mac tracker is sick, I forgot about this, though its way better for seeing every mac that ever existed. +1